# CPU and core usage stats

Tags: cpu, top

I'm running some programs on a server and I would like to know how much % cpu I'm taking up and how many cores are being utilised by my process.

To clarify, the server has 16 CPUs, all quad-core. I know about the top command, but that just continually reports CPU% between 80% and 100.2%.

I also tried `mpstat -P ALL` but I'm really not sure how to read this table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using top, press **'1'** and you should see the different CPUs (or VCPUS) and their load distribution. Probably top reports 80% but not all the CPUs are busy, with this option you should be able to see something else. On other hand you can try [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/)