# top command on multi core processor

Tags: linux, top, parallelism, cpu-usage

I am using freescale IMX6 quad processor. I want to know if the `top` command lists the CPU usage of all 4 cores or of a single core. I am seeing an application's CPU usage being the same with 4 cores and with a single core. I was guessing the CPU usage by the application will increase on a single core and decrease on 4 cores but it has not changed.

Comment: try pressing 1 while top is running

Comment: Could you please elaborate. As in what happens if I press 1. Because I am getting this inconsistent result since 2 days.

Comment: you may find this link useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41311/cpu-and-core-usage-stats

Comment: Which application is that? Why do you think your application should use multiple cores if available? There are many applications out there that work on a single CPU/core and for which nobody bothered to take the time to parallize them.

Comment: @Anthon well that's the question, if top gives you a percentage of 4core or a percentage of a core, because if the percentage comes from 4 cores, then the value (even with a non threaded app should be 4 time fewer

Comment: no. if multiple cores, they accumulate to over 100%. 4 cores can get as high as 800% with hyperthreading on each core

Comment: I like to use `htop` for this.

Comment: pressing 1 does not help is I grep a specific process. i.e top | grep <process-name> followed by 1 does not show cpu core info

Comment: Then `top | awk '/(Cpu|<proc-Name>)/'` will show you Cpu and that one process. Then press `1` to list Cpus separately. But `top` is not designed for piping. You can specify list of pids (by number) on command line. But Cpu is still total of all processes, not just the ones you list.

Comment: related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342889/how-do-i-measure-separate-cpu-core-usage-for-a-process

Answer (score 111):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Yes, `top` shows CPU usage as a percentage of a single CPU by default. That's why you can have percentages that are >100. On a system with 4 cores, you can see up to 400% CPU usage.

You can change this behavior by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (that's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> and toggles "Irix mode") while `top` is running. That will cause it to show the pecentage of available CPU power being used. As explained in `man top`:

```
    1. %CPU  --  CPU Usage
       The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen
       update, expressed as a percentage of total  CPU  time.   In  a
       true  SMP environment, if 'Irix mode' is Off, top will operate
       in 'Solaris mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided  by
       the  total  number  of  CPUs.  You toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes
       with the 'I' interactive command.
```

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>1</kbd> which will show you a breakdown of CPU usage per CPU:

```
top - 13:12:58 up 21:11, 17 users,  load average: 0.69, 0.50, 0.43
Tasks: 248 total,   3 running, 244 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  : 33.3 us, 33.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 33.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 16.7 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 60.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8186416 total,  6267232 used,  1919184 free,   298832 buffers
KiB Swap:  8191996 total,        0 used,  8191996 free,  2833308 cached
```

Comment: with hyperthread I believe you can see up to 800% as /proc/cpuinfo will show each thread as a cpu

Comment: @Dani_l yes, whether the "core" is physical or virtual is irrelevant, it is treated as a "CPU" by `top`. The output I show is from my laptop which has a single physical CPU with two cores, each of which has a 2nd logical core. The result is that `top` sees 4 cores.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, in my dayjob we have to distinguish between sockets, cores and threads when reserving resources. I guess the habit stuck.

Comment: so is it correct to assume that if 'nvproc --all' returns 20 that the CPU % reported by htop per-process should be divided by 20 to get the actual percentage of total CPU capability available?  e.g. htop reporting 54.2% for a process in this context would actually represent 2.71% total CPU usage by that process?

Comment: @CCJ `htop` should show a breakdown by CPU anyway (this was about `top`), but yes, in the percentage column you should divide by the number of available cores.

Answer (score 16):

If you're wanting to open `top` immediately displaying separate CPUs without needing to press `1`, you can use the `-1` option.

e.g.:

`top -1`

```
...
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 44.7 us, 55.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 46.7 us, 53.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
...
```

Note: This works on Debian, but the variant of top installed may vary depending on distro.

Comment: On Gnu/Linux 3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 I don't see this working

Answer (score 6):

If you want `top` command to display per CPU usage everytime you run `top`.

- run `top` command
- press `1`, this will display per CPU usage
- Type `W` and press `Enter` to save configuration to file
- Next time running `top` will display per CPU usage.
- This way we can configure top to our custom requirement

(Above steps works with top version `procps-ng 3.3.12`)