# How come the top command displays >80% CPU idle time but individual processes use >80% CPU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top

Please see screenshot below. The values highlighted jump between 80 and 95 percent.

[image]

As you can see, the postgres process is taking up all the CPU. However, the user processes percentage is only 5%. As a matter of fact, the majority of the CPU is considered idle. The dashboard on Google Cloud also says that the machine has most CPU idle.

I've collected information here [Linux "top" command: What are us, sy, ni, id, wa, hi, si and st (for CPU usage)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/linux-top-command-what-are-us-sy-ni-id-wa-hi-si-and-st-for-cpu-usage)

and here: https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-linuxs-cpu-stats

The latter source specifically says that databases are part of the 'user space' part. How can this discrepancy be explained? Does it have something to do with different CPU cores?

**Update**:

Pressing `1` after doing the `top` command displays cpu use per core:

[image]

There are 18 (!) CPU cores. As you can see, one of them is totally eaten up by postgres but the rest is empty. Am I to understand that the %CPU as listed in the top command only shows how much it takes of a single core? This was not clear to me from the sources I have found.

Taking a more solution oriented approach: Adding more cores won't do anything. Rather expanding the size of the CPU running the postgres process could potentially lower the CPU percentage it uses?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have? The %CPUs line at the top is an average for all CPUs: the per-process is %age of one CPU. Press `1` in top to list all CPUs separately.

Comment: Notably, the "scout" article says *the* CPU throughout.

Comment: Relevant: [top command on multi core processor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146090) and [Understanding top command in unix](https://superuser.com/a/575330)

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, the postgres process is taking up all the CPU.

No, it's taking up a single CPU core - that's what 100% under Unix/Linux means. And even that is not precise.

Your postgres process may have two active threads each taking 50% of two different CPU cores and `top` / `ps` will report 100%.

> Does it have something to do with different CPU cores?

Yes.

> As you can see, one of them is totally eaten up by postgres but the rest is empty.

On your screenshot there are two busy CPU cores, one 88%, another one 9%. Their sum is close to what your posgres is using.

> Adding more cores won't do anything.

It depends however in your particular situation it seems like whatever workload you're running it's bounded by single-threaded CPU performance, so you're correct.

> Rather expanding the size of the CPU running the postgres process could potentially lower the CPU percentage it uses?

I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In addition to that (or, in other words), 17 idle CPUs out of 18 available is 94.4% idle, and that's what the header shows.  The `postgres` process is using 97+% of a single CPU.

Comment: What is your reason for regarding high CPU usage as a bad thing? If it is properly cooled, it does no damage. The scheduler could process each timeslice on a different CPU (it may already be doing this: System Monitor would show you).

Comment: ... in fact, seeing postgrep (arithmetically) used 88% of cpu6 and 9% of cpu7 in the (1.5 second ?) `top` sample rate, indicates it is changing CPUs at least once.