# Allow user process to use 100% of CPU

Tags: firefox

It looks like the "Web Content" Child process of my instance of firefox is limited to 25% CPU utilization during heavy loads. I have yet to see it be allowed to exceed this. Is there any way I can modify a setting somewhere to allow the browser to max out my CPU if it needs the resources? I tried setting the priority to high and using `cpulimit` to set the CPU limit to 25%. I'm thinking this has something to do with `cgroups` but I don't know where the default configuration is for firefox. I'm on a Debian machine.

It looks like any process spawned by an unprivileged user is limited to 25% CPU usage.

Comment: That could be down to your distro. I'm running the official Firefox under Fedora 33 and it takes as much CPU time as it needs.

Comment: How do you measure it? If in `top` then maybe [you're in the wrong mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146090/108618). Using Solaris mode when you expect Irix can easily create an impression a single-threaded process is limited while in reality it takes 100% of one core.

Comment: Seems like yes its using 100% of 1 core since its a 4 core system